# How to create a margin between two seperate divs?

Tags: html, css

I have two divs at the moment containing different images and text.   They use the same css style of `.cheese_people`  I need to create a margin between the middle of the two boxes. How would I do this?

Also do I really need two divs to do this?  The only reason I've done it like this is to get them on the same grid line.

```
            <div class=" grid 6 cheese_people">
        <img class="people_photo" src="img/cheese_expert.jpg">
        <h4>Chief Cheese Taster <br> Dave Le Conk</h4>
        <p class="chesse_people">I've always had a passion for cheese - Now I get to taste it everyday!</p>
    </div>

    <div class=" grid 6 cheese_people">
        <img class="people_photo" src="img/cheese_owner.jpg">
        <h4>The Big Cheese Owner <br> Sally De Cheese</h4>
        <p class="chesse_people">I wanted to create an online store that I'd would trust</p>
    </div>

        .cheese_people {
        font-family: sans-serif;
        background-color: #dec38c;
        border:solid 3px #6b5221;
       -moz-border-radius: 5px;
       -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
       border-radius: 5px;
        float:left;
        width:45%;
        }
```

Comment: Have you tried adding ` margin-right: 10px;` for example?

Comment: You could add `margin-right` and remove it from `last-child`

Comment: P.S. You no longer need to define browser prefixes for border-radius: http://caniuse.com/#search=border-radius

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure you want margin between both divs. You might want one sticked to the left, and the other sticked to the right (I say that because of the `45%`). Then, use this :

```
.cheese_people:last-child {float: right}
```

Answer (score 1):

This will only affect the second div:

```
div.cheese_people + div.cheese_people{
    margin-left: 10px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want there to be a space between the two div's, What you can try is giving one an id and then adding CSS to the ID (adding just margin-right: 10px; to the class would add a right margin to both images, if you want space in between the images and no where else, then I would use the ID technique), like so

```
    <div class=" grid 6 cheese_people" id="leftpic">
    <img class="people_photo" src="img/cheese_expert.jpg">
    <h4>Chief Cheese Taster <br> Dave Le Conk</h4>
    <p class="chesse_people">I've always had a passion for cheese - Now I get to taste it everyday!</p>
</div>

<div class=" grid 6 cheese_people">
    <img class="people_photo" src="img/cheese_owner.jpg">
    <h4>The Big Cheese Owner <br> Sally De Cheese</h4>
    <p class="chesse_people">I wanted to create an online store that I'd would trust</p>
</div>

    .cheese_people {
    font-family: sans-serif;
    background-color: #dec38c;
    border:solid 3px #6b5221;
   -moz-border-radius: 5px;
   -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
   border-radius: 5px;
    float:left;
    width:45%;
    }

    #leftpic {
        margin-right: 10px;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can add a class to the first div so you give it the margin

```
    <div class=" grid 6 cheese_people margin-container">
        <img class="people_photo" src="img/cheese_expert.jpg">
        <h4>Chief Cheese Taster <br> Dave Le Conk</h4>
        <p class="chesse_people">I've always had a passion for cheese - Now I get to taste it everyday!</p>
    </div>

    <div class=" grid 6 cheese_people">
        <img class="people_photo" src="img/cheese_owner.jpg">
        <h4>The Big Cheese Owner <br> Sally De Cheese</h4>
        <p class="chesse_people">I wanted to create an online store that I'd would trust</p>
    </div>

        .cheese_people {
        font-family: sans-serif;
        background-color: #dec38c;
        border:solid 3px #6b5221;
       -moz-border-radius: 5px;
       -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
       border-radius: 5px;
        float:left;
        width:45%;
        }

       .margin-container {
            margin-right: 2px solid black;
       }
```

This way if you need to add this margin to other div you just give it the class

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
float:left
float:right
```

For Both Image and Text

In the CSS Class

Use Accordingly